# Jquery get value onClick problems

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get a variable (set on the front end) to be sent through jQuery onClick.

I'm pretty sure it's possible, I just can't figure it out because I'm not familiar with jQuery.

Here is the HTML part:

```
<input type="text" name="quantity" size="2" value="1" />
<input type="button" value="Add to cart" id="button-cart" class="button" />
```

And here is my jQuery part:

```
$('#button-cart').bind('click', function() {
    addToCart(
        '<?php echo $product_id; ?>',
        '$("#quantity").val();'
    );
});
```

But it just doesn't work. I know if I do something like this:

```
$('#button-cart').bind('click', function() {
    addToCart(
        '<?php echo $product_id; ?>',
        '3'
    );
});
```

That it adds 3 items to the cart but the page needs to be dynamic so the user can enter the quantity needed.

I hope it's clear what I'm trying to do. If anybody could help that would be great. Thank you.

Comment: First of all, You need the `DOM ready` handler around the jquery code

Comment: Why is `$("#quantity").val();` part wrapped in single quotes? You don't need them. Of course, you haven't actually shown us what `addToCart` actually looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) that $("#quantity").val(); shouldn't be inside ''

2) use $(document).ready

3) to select by name you should use [name=quantity], not #quantity (that is for ids)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function ()
{
$('#button-cart').click(function() {
    addToCart(
        '<?php echo $product_id; ?>',
        $("input[name=quantity]").val()
    );
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#button-cart').bind('click', function() {
    addToCart(
        '<?php echo $product_id; ?>',
        $("input[name=quantity]").val()
    );
});
</script>
```

Comment: Explain what you changed

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" name="quantity" size="2" value="1" />
 <input type="button" onclick="addToCart('<?php  echo $product_id;?>')" value="Add to cart" id="button-cart" class="button" />



<script>
function addToCart(id){
var quantity=$("input[name=quantity]").val();
var productId=id;

//Do your stuff
}


</script>
```